# Work(flow) Setup: Remote Debian VM (in office), ssh, web development

Tags: web-services, ssh, debian, virtual-machine, frontend

Normally I've developed locally (on my own machine) and pushed to wherever things needed to go via mapped drives, ftp, github, etc. I have done a bit of work with vagrant/virtualbox (but again, locally) with a shared/mirrored folder.

I am now in a situation where everyone here has access to their own dev box (a vm on the network). I see some working in Vim directly via SSH, I believe, but I'm not there yet. So I'm left with the question: What's the best way for (more of a front end guy) to approach this?

I have heard of doing an SSH-mount from my workstation... if that's a viable thing. I'm curious what everyone's take on this kind of environment is and (perhaps) any best practices. Tips, links, and reading is highly welcome and appreciated, too... any pointing in a good direction would be wonderful.

Thank you.

Comment: When someone mentions ssh-mount, he/she must mean sshfs, an ssh-based fuse (filesystem in userspace) filesystem driver. This stuff is quite viable, I've been doing web development, mounting the server space using sshfs and working directly on this filesystem, for years. It was literally flawless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer will come from what virtual resources do you want to capitalize on for the virtual networked VMs. If you just want the storage space, then share the VM's drives, and mount them locally, treat them as local, end of story. If you want to run all the processing on the remote machine, and connect from a thin client, you have a couple of options, but they all take the same form.  Connect to the machine, edit the files on the remote machine.  Depending on your OS, you will have different options available.

- If the remote machine doesn't have an graphical client installed you are stuck with either, mounting the remote share locally (you can use whatever editor you want) or ssh to the remote machine and using a commandline editor (vim, nano, emacs).
- If there is a graphical client installed you have more options:

  - Remote in the server using any visual viewer (mstsc for windows, vnc is an option), and then use any remotely installed editor of your choice.
  - Remote in using ssh -X, and then run the remotely installed editor.  Assuming you have an X-Server locally (if you are running linux you already do), the GUI part of the application will be run on the client side of the ssh tunnel, and the process will be run on the server.  This is probably the best option.

So:

- Make sure the remote server has a desktop client software (gtk, kde, gnome, almost any windows os, etc...)
- install GUI editor of your choice on that server
- `ssh -X` to that server
- install sublime text, geany, or your choice of editor
- run `subl`, `geany`, or other to start the application.

Comment: well, ssh X11 forwarding may come with much higher network traffic overhead than a network filesystem, not to mention the flawed user experience upon higher network load. I would not recommend going this way where a network mount is an acceptable solution either.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to optimize for, if you are looking to get the benefit of a remote server with high performance, storage, internet, which you don't have locally, X would be a good option.  If you have a beast under (or on top of your desk), and you are just looking for a backup solution then `rsync` would be better. There is a large spectrum of what you can implement, it just depends on your goals.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Warren. This is a good baseline for me (and hopefully others), along with the comments here! At the moment, I am using SFTP NetDrive (free) for SSH mapping from my Win box, Sublime, and using HeidiSQL for the DB client (and of course an SSH client for dealing with permissions, etc). Furthermore, on the remote box I've loaded Laravel (Lumen, specifically), Apache2/MySQL, Composer, etc... then just hit the ip of the remote box to test/view.

Answer (score 1):

SSH mounting would indeed allow you to use all of the files on the VM as if they were stored in your local machine, letting you edit and update files without having to manually copy them every time you perform changes. You will run into a speed bump though, since files changed will have to be synchronized/copied to your remote machine every time and that takes a couple of seconds. Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) post by DigitalOcean, they explain how to get the SSH mount working.

A better option you have (IMHO) is to use an [IDE in your local machine that allows you to push changes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm) to a server after saving or by manually doing so. This would allow you to develop faster by using your local resources (local web server) since no files would have to be copied over the network to the remote VM; and would also allow you to test on that remote VM when needed by uploading the files when you are ready to test on that environment.

PS: Exporting visual apps or environments form the remote machine to your local one can be slow (depending on your network and the VM host load running your machine). If you still like that approach, you could also install something to access that VM over something more standard and lightweight like RDP for GNU/Linux (xrdp).

Comment: Thank you for this response -- I had not considered working locally (unfortunately I'm on a Windows box at the moment, however), my main deterrent would be having proper permissions/taxonomy between my (lets say) WAMP and the remote machine, Debian (Jessie).